# jquery list box plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, user-interface

I am looking for a java jquery listbox plugin for performing few operations, where I searched in google but dint find any appropriate plugin.

I have a  requirement like I should have two list box where I can shuffle the values from left listbox to right list box and vise versa. 
Items listed in left listbox should be sorted at any point. Should be able to drag and drop the items within the right list box for changing the positions of items in right listbox alone.

Can anyone suggest a jquery plugin for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this gets you pretty close, maybe you can configure it further?

http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBPlugin.aspx